# How to make a histogram of pandas datetimes per specific time interval?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to plot some datetimes and would like to specify a time interval in order to bundle them together and make a histogram. So for example, if there happen to be n datetimes in the span of one hour, group them together or parse them as year, month, day, hour. And omit minutes and seconds.
Let's say I have a data frame with some datetime values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'col2': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
print(df)

2018-06-19 17:10:32.076646    29
2018-06-20 17:10:32.076646    56
2018-06-21 17:10:32.076646    82
2018-06-22 17:10:32.076646    13
2018-06-23 17:10:32.076646    35
2018-06-24 17:10:32.076646    53
2018-06-25 17:10:32.076646    25
2018-06-26 17:10:32.076646    23
```

Ideally, I would like to specify a more flexible time interval, such as "6 hours" in order to make some sort of modulo operation on the datetimes. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `pd.cut` and then specify your bins with `pd.date_range` which will allow you to specify sensible regular intervals like `freq='6H'`. Or perhaps just [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html). If you need more help, you should edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for not providing a MCVE. I hope this helps. The approaches you mentioned sound very promising. How would I do this with the help of pd.cut or pd.Grouper? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `pd.Grouper`

Allows you to specify regular frequency intervals with which you will group your data. Use `groupby` to then aggregate your `df` based on these groups. For instance, if `col2` was counts and you wanted to bin together all of the counts over 2 day intervals, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='2D')).col2.sum()
```

Outputs:

```
test
2018-06-19 13:49:11.560185    85
2018-06-21 13:49:11.560185    95
2018-06-23 13:49:11.560185    88
2018-06-25 13:49:11.560185    48
Name: col2, dtype: int32
```

You group by `level=0`, that is your index labeled `'test'` and sum `col2` over 2 day bins. The behavior of `pd.Grouper` can be a little annoying since in this example the bins start and end at 13:49:11..., which likely isn't what you want.

#### `pd.cut` + `pd.date_range`

You have a bit more control over defining your bins if you define them with `pd.date_range` and then use `pd.cut`. Here for instance, you can define bins every 2 days beginning on the 19th.

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, 
                  pd.date_range('2018-06-19', '2018-06-27', freq='2D'))).col2.sum()
```

Outputs:

```
(2018-06-19, 2018-06-21]    85
(2018-06-21, 2018-06-23]    95
(2018-06-23, 2018-06-25]    88
(2018-06-25, 2018-06-27]    48
Name: col2, dtype: int32
```

This is nice, because if you instead wanted the bins to begin on even days you can just change the start and end dates in `pd.date_range`

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, 
                  pd.date_range('2018-06-18', '2018-06-28', freq='2D'))).col2.sum()
```

Outputs:

```
(2018-06-18, 2018-06-20]     29
(2018-06-20, 2018-06-22]    138
(2018-06-22, 2018-06-24]     48
(2018-06-24, 2018-06-26]     78
(2018-06-26, 2018-06-28]     23
Name: col2, dtype: int32
```

If you really wanted to, you could specify 2.6 hour bins beginning on June 19th 2018 at 5 AM:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, 
                  pd.date_range('2018-06-19 5:00:00', '2018-06-28 5:00:00', freq='2.6H'))).col2.sum()
#(2018-06-19 05:00:00, 2018-06-19 07:36:00]     0
#(2018-06-19 07:36:00, 2018-06-19 10:12:00]     0
#(2018-06-19 10:12:00, 2018-06-19 12:48:00]     0
#(2018-06-19 12:48:00, 2018-06-19 15:24:00]    29
#....
```

#### Histogram.

Just use `.plot(kind='bar')` after you have aggregated the data.

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, 
                   pd.date_range('2018-06-19', '2018-06-28', freq='2D')))
   .col2.sum().plot(kind='bar', color='firebrick', rot=30))
```

[image]

Comment: That is just perfect. Thank you so much. The pd.Grouper solution is perfect for my use case.